# Microsoft.Bot.Connector.DirectLine Support in .NET MAUI

Tags: botframework, maui, .net-maui

I am converting my Xamarin Forms Application to .NET MAUI.

In existing app we have used Microsoft.Bot.Connector.DirectLine(3.0.2) for using the Bot Framework Direct Line REST API.

Is Microsoft.Bot.Connector.DirectLine package supported in .net MAUI?

In the [Microsoft.Bot.Connector.DirectLine Nuget Link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bot.Connector.DirectLine/3.0.2?_src=template#supportedframeworks-body-tab) I don't see the net6.0 as the compatible target framework.   [image]
If it's not supported is there any alternative package?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Did you try adding it to your project?

Comment: Yes, It's throwing below error "The package is missing the required nuspec file. Path: C:\Users\Mars\.nuget\packages\system.text.encoding.extensions\4.3.0" even though the system.text.encoding.extensions is available in the above path

Answer (score 1):

This is an old package which hasn't been updated since 2017. It likely doesn't support .NET 6.0 and probably won't be updated to support it.

The good news is that you do not need this package to communicate with a bot over Direct Line. You can use .NET Standard Library objects (such as [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-6.0)) to communicate with Direct Line as you would any other REST API. There may be other libraries and frameworks you could use as well.

See the [Direct Line 3.0 Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-concepts?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) to see how to use the API.